# Vlookup in VBA runs very slow, any ideas?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have created the following macro to be able to have a sheet called "Macron" which looks inside different cells and sheets in my workbook, from there i want to create a macro that finds the value based on a name instead of a specific cell (since VBA code does not get updated if i add another cell etc, then i need to rewrite all the macro references which is extremely timeconsuming).

So i decided to work with the application.Vlookup function in my code, but now i see that this goes extremely slow compared to only looking inside the cells.

Is this the case all the time, or is it something wrong with my code that could be updated or cleaner to make it work faster.

Here is my code for the macro:

```
Sub Motesbokning_saljare()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim a As String
Dim o As String
Dim a1 As String
Dim o1 As String
Dim strbody As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

' ä
a = Chr(228)
'å
a1 = Chr(229)
'ö
o = Chr(246)
'Ö
o1 = Chr(214)

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)
Set ws = Sheets("Macron")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Offert")

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Application.VLookup("kundEpost", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False)
    .Subject = Application.VLookup("partnerNamn", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & ", " & Application.VLookup("kundFulltNamn", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False)
    .location = "" & Application.VLookup("kundAdress", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & ", " & Application.VLookup("kundPostnr", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & ", " & Application.VLookup("kundPostort", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False)
    .Body = "Projekttyp: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("moteProjekttyp", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & "Fastighetstyp: " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("moteFastighetstyp", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Portkod: " & _
    Application.VLookup("motePortkod", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & "Telefon: " & Application.VLookup("kundTelefon", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & "V" & a1 & "ning: " & Application.VLookup("moteVaning", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "Upphandlingsunderlag: " & Application.VLookup("moteUpphandlingsunderlag", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & Application.VLookup("moteUpphandlingsunderlagTyp", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "K" & o & "rtid: " & Application.VLookup("moteKortid", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & " minuter" _
    & vbNewLine & "GPS URL: " & Application.VLookup("moteGPSurl", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "K" & a & "lla: " & Application.VLookup("moteKalla", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & o1 & "vrigt: " & Application.VLookup("moteOvriginfo", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Referenskund i n" & a & _
    "romr" & a1 & "de: " & vbNewLine & ws1.Range("I35").Value & ", " & ws1.Range("K35").Value & ", " & ws1.Range("M35").Value & vbNewLine & ws1.Range("I36").Value & ", " & _
    ws1.Range("K36").Value & ", " & ws1.Range("M36").Value & vbNewLine & ws1.Range("I37").Value & ", " & ws1.Range("K37").Value & ", " & ws1.Range("M37").Value & vbNewLine & _
    ws1.Range("I38").Value & ", " & ws1.Range("K38").Value & ", " & ws1.Range("M38").Value & vbNewLine & ws1.Range("I39").Value & ", " & ws1.Range("K39").Value & ", " _
    & ws1.Range("M39").Value
    .Start = Application.VLookup("moteDatum", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False) + Application.VLookup("moteKlockslag", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False)
    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Application.VLookup("moteReminder", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False)
    .Duration = Application.VLookup("moteTidsatgang", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False)
    .Recipients.Add Application.VLookup("moteLaggTillDeltagare", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False)
    .Categories = Application.VLookup("moteKategori", ws.Range("A:C").Value, 3, False)
    .Display
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help that can be offered.

Best regards
Agatonsaxx

Comment: You are doing a lot of vLookups running over the whole column. If you have a lot of data in there a linear search will be very slow.

Comment: Wow, that is a huge block. You're always having the lookup data in column a and the returned value in column c. Try iterating over column a once, saving any found index of a string to an array. Then, fill the mail body according to that array. For instance: The first entry of the array would be the row where you find the string "kundEpost" in column a and so on, then afterwards, the first part of the mail body would be the value of the cell (x, 3) where x stands for the first array entry.

Comment: Hi so if i for example would have A1:C200 that would work a lot faster? Instead of looking inside the whole column?

Comment: @AgatonSaxx that would probably help, too

Comment: EngJon thanks for your quick answer, i am not very familiar with arrays, could you perhaps give me a code example to show how this would work? Do you mean to make all of this in the VBA code or inside the actuall sheet? My issue with using cells, are that everytime someone comes up with a new attribute and i add it into the sheet (macron), then all the references to different cells are screwed up and i need to go inside the VBA code again to change from e.g. Range("B1").Value to Range("B2").Value. But you perhaps mean to do all of this in the actual vba code in some smart way?

Comment: I also had an idea now to do the following, but it does not really work as i want. If i declare a range as following:

    Dim rng As Range    

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C80")

    .To = Application.VLookup("kundEpost", ws.Range(rng).Value, 3, False)

But then it did not look inside any of the cells i declared in the other sheet. Everything just got blank, something wrong with my rng or with the Vlookupcode?

Comment: Using FIND rather than a VLOOKUP function would be a whole lot faster - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: For your last comment: You need to use only `rng`,  not `ws.Range(rng).Value`. That way it may work. To my proposal: I'll give you some code in an answer to show you how I meant it.

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone! EngJon i would gladly take some code examples from you. Now when i specified rng and only lookup in cell A1 - C80 the code goes way faster. But i would like to see your examples to see if it can be even faster.

Comment: Another thing related to this subject if anyone knows. Is it possible to declare a formula saying something like this: "Count all the rows where there is text and return that value inside another cell". What i want is for my range to automatically change when i add a new row or add text in another cell. Do you understand what i mean with that?

Comment: There is simple VBA code for the last row. In my answer I even used one of the possible ways. You could write a userfunction (`Public Function lastRow(column As String) As Long ... End Function` with that line defined as the return statement taking `column` as parameter) and use it inside excel cells.

Comment: VLOOKUP in Excel versions as of (I think) 2010 is smart enough to (internally) intersect the entire column with the used range prior to doing the lookup. So referring to the entire column shouldn't make much of a differnce.

Comment: You might be better off posting this to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  It's a forum for improving code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip the tremendous amount of vlookups (combined with them being for whole columns and not smaller defined ranges), while using VBA I suggest using a single iteration over column A to determine the contents of your mail body. For that purpose you need 2 arrays. One for the words you are looking for in column A (`searchWords`) and one for the needed values in column C (`mailContents`). My approach would be as follows ("..." marking skips that need to be filled in with your existing code):

```
Sub Motesbokning_saljare()
    ...
    Set ws = Sheets("Macron")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Offert")

    Dim searchWords(1 To 100) As String
    'Fill all the words that need to be searched:
    searchWords(1) = "kundEPost"
    searchWords(2) = "partnerNamn"
    searchWords(3) = "kundFulltNamn"
    ...
    Dim mailContents(1 To 100) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        'i is for the rows of the excel sheet
        For j = 1 To UBound(searchWords)
            'j is for the lookup in the array searchwords
            If ws.Cells(i, 1) = searchWords(j) Then
                mailContents(j) = ws.Cells(i, 3)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    'Now, fill the mail body:
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = mailContents(1)
        .Subject = mailContents(2) & ", " & mailContents(3)
        ...
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    ...
End Sub
```

As you can see, I only filled in the first 3 words of the mail body. You'd need to fill `searchWords` with the mail body lookups and further fill the mail body. I'd also recommend to change the size of the arrays to the exact number of lookups your formerly did (1 To 100 means that it can contain up to 100 entries).

Comment: Great answer, thanks for your code and i will definately try this!

One thing i need to know, the cells where searchwords should look in are the "Macron" sheet, which i have declared as Dim ws. But where should this information go in the code? I will be using the macro in another sheet than where the data is specified.

Comment: Hope this helps, good luck on further speeding up your code ;)

Comment: Not sure I'd use the `On Error Resume Next` while creating the email - it may be better to create the whole email correctly or not at all and let the user know the problem.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Good point, I just lazily copied parts of the original code without further insight. Would be better to have it your way.

Comment: I will remove the on error resume next in the code. Any tips for my question above regarding how the "Searchwords" would know where to look for the actual words?

Comment: Now when i try to run the macro, it says on the following code:

 For j = 1 To Len(searchWords)

that a variable need to be defined. Is this because i have not used
Set searchWords = something?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understood your question in the first comment to this answer. The iteration always looks in column A (Cells(row, column), column 1 is therefore column A) and looks for every row in that column (since `LastRow` is defined for the last row in column A). Which information do you now want to get into the code?

Comment: Hi again, now i get an error when running the code, it does not say anything except when it goes to .To it gets yellow and the code does not run. I guess this is because it is looking inside the wrong sheet, i have changed "with ActiveSheet" to with Sheets("macron"), but does not seem to help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it look in column A in every sheet in the document? Otherwise i guess i need to specify in which sheet to look in? The macro is executed in another sheet than where the data is.

Comment: Now it says "Object does not support the property or method" and points to the .To = mailContents(1)

Comment: Hmm, I did never fill a mail body via Excel, so I just copied your existing code for the part of the construction of the mail body. I changed the code to reference the correct sheet. You did fill the "..." parts with your code, didn't you?

Comment: Well i agree this is weird, i have now added everything and everything looks correct. In the .To field it finds my email adress etc. But it still says that it does not support the property or method. Very strange. Perhaps it is only in the "Body" part i should use this code and in the other fields I use my original code with the Vlookup.

Comment: Aha i found the issue. The "On error resume next" i have that because this macro should actually open up outlook and create a meeting, so the ".To" field is not declared until i open up outlook. Now i understand why it is there. Do you know how i can specify so that this is automatically filled in instead of having to add it when outlook opens?

Comment: You could open Outlook from your vba code (add references in vba and Dim an Outlook object, then open it), but I'm not sure this will help in your case. Unfortunately, I did not use Excel-vba and Outlook combined yet.

Comment: Alright thanks alot for your help with all of this. Now i think i will manage on my own :)

Comment: EngJon, I have a question i am using your code in several macros and sometimes i execute several macros within another macro. Sometimes it seems that the Vlookup function does not find the values. I guess this is because it loops through things and perhaps it ends in a weird position or something. Is there anyway of "resetting" the loop so that it always start from the top and goes down? Because i see that when i execute a macro several times it sometimes misses some fields and when i run it again suddenly the data is there again. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.